# Can I synchronize the update process between two PCs?

Tags: 14.04, updates, sync

I have a laptop and a desktop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on both of them.

If there is an update I have to do it to both of them, but if there is anyway that I can synchronize the update process between them so I only download the update on one of them and apply it to both of them that would be great to reduce the consumption of the Internet resources?

Comment: A possible solution for you could be creating your own local repository.
You can find instructions for instance [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository).

Comment: You probably don't want the identical installation on both computers since they require different drivers for the hardware.

Comment: - Create my own repository then what it's the same as downloading the updates on both computer. @Bruni

Comment: - Other than hardware drivers the most common are programs software and Ubuntu-Base Package, and i think i it the same for all computers. @LDC3

Comment: I thought the point was reducing bandwith. If you create your own repo from the files downloaded on one of the computers and use this as a repo for the second, you reduce internet bandwith (provided they are in the same local network). You could also use an external drive for this.

Comment: That might work, but can i make an offline repository for my network only? @Bruni

Comment: If you read through the first answer of the post I linked you to (by BigSack), you can see that you don't even need to setup a web server to make a local repository. A local repository can be a directory on computer 1, that you share (e.g. by samba) to computer 2. On computer 2, you  mount this directory, and add it to your Sources.list file. Don't forget the update script. The part that is missing from the puzzle is getting the .debs you want.

Comment: I think this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/15211/saving-deb-files-from-repositories-to-a-custom-location-for-installing-offline could  help you for that part.